# How to validate IP Address to make sure user enter 3 digits in four parts?

Tags: javascript

I was able to create a script to validate IP address correctly like this,

```
var ipformat = /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;

if(g_form.getValue('src_nw_ip_hdcc').match(ipformat)){
    return true;
}else{
    alert("You have entered an invalid Network IP Address!");
    return false;
}
```

The results was great but until then they made a unusual request that they require me to validate user enter 3 digits and not allow enter 1 or 2 digits like for example,
user can't enter 115.42.150.37, instead must enter 115.042.150.037. How can I add verify to ensure they enter 3 digits?

Comment: That's a very strange requirement. Many IP parsers interpret leading zeroes to mean octal rather than decimal, so those addresses would not be parsed the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by removing alls "?" in the regex.
This way your regex requires 3 digits every time and accepts things like 192.168.001.001

```
^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01][0-9][0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01][0-9][0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01][0-9][0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01][0-9][0-9])$
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code it has `[01]?[0-9][0-9]`. It says it can have a leading 0 or 1 or not followed by two numbers. Simple fix is to remove the `?` where it makes the 0 and 1 optional

```
/^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01][0-9][0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01][0-9][0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01][0-9][0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01][0-9][0-9])$/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this regex will do the job. Hope this helps.

```js
const regex = /^(((25[0-5])|(2[0-4][0-9])|([01][0-9]{2}))\.){3}((25[0-5])|(2[0-4][0-9])|([01][0-9]{2}))$/g;

console.log('Should match');
console.log('255.255.255.255'.match(regex));
console.log('012.000.255.001'.match(regex));
console.log('000.000.000.000'.match(regex));

console.log('Should not match');
console.log('255.255.255.'.match(regex));
console.log('255.255.255.-1'.match(regex));
console.log('.255.255.'.match(regex));
console.log('255.275.255.'.match(regex));
console.log('255.275.255.1'.match(regex));
console.log('25.5.55.1'.match(regex));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `split()` and `every()` in conjunction to get that validation work:

```js
function checkIp(ip) {
  var isCorrect = ip.split('.').every(addr => addr.length === 3);
  if (isCorrect) {
    return 'Ip address is correct';
  }
  return 'Ip address is incorrect';
}
var ip = '115.042.150.037';
console.log(checkIp(ip));

ip = '11.042.150.037';
console.log(checkIp(ip));
```